# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Password' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `rerationforms` in laravel 10

Tags: laravel

I am doing a Laravel project. I got an error when developing password validation. I need your help if you are an expert in Laravel. this is my humble request to you. Thanks in advance.

** HTML`:**

```
`<div class="input-field">
            <label for="pw" >Password</label>
            <div class="inpt">
                <input type="Password" id="pw" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <label for="cpw" >Confirm Password</label>
            <div class="inpt">
            <input type="password" id="cpw" name="password_confirmation"  placeholder="Enter     Confirm Password">
             </div>
        </div>
```

`
**Migration:**

```
`$table->string('Password');
        $table->string('Password_confirmation');`
```

**controller:**

```
` public function store(Request $request):RedirectResponse{
   ` 
   
    Registrationform::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('register');

    $validation = $request->validate([
        'password' => 'required|confirmed'
    ]);
```

`
**SQL Mode:**

```
 [sql Mode setting in local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Hvm.png)
sql mode    NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,​NO_ZERO_DATE,​NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

**Error:**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Password' doesn't have a default value (Connection: MySQL, SQL: insert into `registration forms` (`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `E_mail`, `ConfirmE_mail`, `Gender`, `birthday_day`, `birthday_month`, `birthday_year`, `UserName`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (crafts, fsdfds, aziz1@gmail.com, aziz2@gmail.com, O, 27, 6, 2023, dafs, 2023-07-08 03:51:29, 2023-07-08 03:51:29))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason you getting this error is because of your db column name is `Password` and form input field name is `password`. `Create()` method is trying to search value for column `Password` but it is not in your request, and in your migration you have set it as not null.

To fix this issue, you can update your migration file.

```
$table->string('password');
$table->string('password_confirmation');
```

Else you can simply rename the input field names

```
<div class="input-field">
            <label for="pw" >Password</label>
            <div class="inpt">
                <input type="Password" id="pw" name="Password" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <label for="cpw" >Confirm Password</label>
            <div class="inpt">
            <input type="password" id="cpw" name="Password_confirmation"  placeholder="Enter Confirm Password">
             </div>
        </div>
```

Read more about [migration tips and tricks](https://www.laravelicious.com/laravel-migration-from-basics-expert-level/)

Comment: Thank You Hercules73. I got the solution.